# Regex to match parenthesis and its contents if it does not start with an underscore

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex:

```
\([^\(]*?\)
```

Which matches parenthesis of a String and the contents within the parenthesis. I would like it to only match if there is no _ before the parenthesis.

For example I would like it to match (text) in this example:

> This is some random (text)

But I do not want it to match anything in this example:

> This is another_(text)

How would I go about this?

Comment: No regex *directly* before the bracket, or somewhere before?

Comment: Directly before the bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***negative lookbehind*** for that:

```
  (?<!_)\([^\(]*\)
# ^ negative lookbehind
```

As is demonstrated in this [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/nLmxgR/2)

Like [@SebastianProske](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738651/regex-to-match-paranthesis-and-its-contents-if-it-does-not-start-with-an-undersc/44738669#comment76458769_44738669) says, there is no reason to make `[^\(]` greedy: since it will never match a closing bracket. So I made it greedy.

Comment: @SebastianProske: fixed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! This is understandable and simple

Answer (score 1):

Add negative lookbehind: `(?<!_)` checking just what you said (*no "_" before*).

One more remark: the content between both parentheses should be any sequence of
chars but other than **closing** one.

So the whole regex should be:

```
(?<!_)\([^\)]*\)
```